# when running my java code i am facing this error ->

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

my code:

```
public static void loanenquiry(String ApplicationID,String LoanNumber,String RIMNumber,String custname,String fromdate,String todate) {
    String wherestring = "SELECT * FROM bf_loanmaster WHERE";       

    try {
        if(ApplicationID != null) {
            wherestring = wherestring + "ApplicationID ="+BillAction.StringtoInt(ApplicationID)+"";
        }

        if(LoanNumber != null ) {
            if(ApplicationID != null) {
                wherestring =  wherestring  +  "AND LoanNumber = "+BillAction.StringtoInt(LoanNumber)+" ";
            } else {
                wherestring =  wherestring  +  "LoanNumber = "+BillAction.StringtoInt(LoanNumber)+" ";
            }
        }

        if(RIMNumber != null ) {
            if(ApplicationID != null && LoanNumber != null) { 
                wherestring =  wherestring  + "AND AdvparyRIM = "+RIMNumber+" ";
            } else {
                wherestring =  wherestring  + "AdvparyRIM = "+RIMNumber+"";
            }
        }

        if(custname != null ){
            if(ApplicationID != null && LoanNumber != null && RIMNumber != null ) {
                wherestring =  wherestring  +  "AND custName = "+custname+"";
            } else {
                wherestring =  wherestring  +  "custName = "+custname+"";
            }
        }

        if(fromdate != null ) {
            if(ApplicationID != null && LoanNumber != null && RIMNumber != null && custname != null ) {
                wherestring =  wherestring  +  "AND ApplicationDt >= "+BillAction.StringtoDate(fromdate)+" ";
            } else {
                wherestring =  wherestring  +  "ApplicationDt = "+BillAction.StringtoDate(fromdate)+"";
            }
        }
        if(todate != null ) {
            if(ApplicationID != null && LoanNumber != null && RIMNumber != null && custname != null && fromdate != null) {
                wherestring =  wherestring  +  "AND ApplicationDt >= "+BillAction.StringtoDate(fromdate)+" AND ApplicationDt <= "+BillAction.StringtoDate(todate)+"";
            } else {
                wherestring =  wherestring  +  "ApplicationDt >= "+BillAction.StringtoDate(todate)+"";
            }
        }

        Connection conn = BillFinanceDB.getDBConnection();
        PreparedStatement psloanenquiry= conn.prepareStatement(wherestring + ";");
        ResultSet rs =  psloanenquiry.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("loan number"+rs.getInt("LoanNumber"));
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

thanks for the help.

Comment: Post the exact error trace and also the **final query** which is getting executed!

Comment: there is one problem with your sql, please post the final value of the variable wherestring

Comment: you forgot the `AND` in every `else` branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess:  you're missing a space after `WHERE` in your constructed string.  Try this:

```
String wherestring = "SELECT * FROM bf_loanmaster WHERE ";
```

The best way to debug these kinds of errors is to print out the SQL query you have constructed before it is executed so that you can manually inspect it for problems.

Comment: The same issue exists in the clauses as well

Comment: Spaces are required other places also. you must print the query and understand the problem.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of problems to address, but printing the query is the first step!

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` is most likely a problem. The second problem that you could have is not putting your strings in quotation marks. For example it probably should be `wherestring =  wherestring  +  "custName = '"+custname+"' ";`

Also things to note:

All this appending is terribly inefficient, use a StringBuilder or StringBuffer instead. You could also use PreparedStatements which would make your code perform better and possibly even make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Add a space after where.. You have to seperate keywords like where..

Answer (score 0):

give a space in your query

```
String wherestring = "SELECT * FROM bf_loanmaster WHERE";
```

there is no space between WHERE statement and condition.